# cannot find symbol AudioSynthesizer deeplearning4j examples

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

I've downloaded the deeplearning4j examples as descriped in the quickstart guide using git and maven. When I try to start an 
example with IntelliJ there comes up an Error.

I tried to add some more dependencys in my `pom.xml` but dont find the right one. 
On top there there are many(!) warnings about deprecated classes, followed by an Error:

> Error:(7, 27) java: package com.sun.media.sound does not exist
>
> Error:(43, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>       symbol:   class AudioSynthesizer
>       location: class org.deeplearning4j.examples.recurrent.character.harmonies.Midi2WavRenderer

I use the JDK12, latest maven and examples.

Answer (score 1):

On **IntelliJ/File/Project Structure.../Project Settings/Project/Project SDK**
select, say, Java version 1.8, would solve this problem.

**Deeplearning4j** depends on **com.sun.media.sound** package to compile. Since recent **IntelliJ** comes with JDK 11 as default, which does not include such package. You have to install JDK version 8, which include the above mentioned package, then manually select JDK8's installation location under IntelliJ's **File/Project Structure.../Project Settings/Project/Project SDK**. My **Deeplearning4j** project can be compiled successfully after such modification. Good luck!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. Please explain your answer with some more details so user can understand it well.

Comment: **Deeplearning4j** depending on **com.sun.media.sound** package, since recent **IntelliJ** comes with Java version 11 as default, which does not include such package. You have to install JDK version 8, which include the above mentioned package, then manually select JDK 8 under IntelliJ's **File/Project Structure.../Project Settings/Project/Project SDK** to manually select JDK8's installation location.  @user5497819